# How to update multiple views with separate controllers in MVVM

Tags: python, tkinter, design-patterns

Level: beginner

Language: python, using TKinter to build the GUI

Application: RC rover control station

Design pattern used: Model View ViewModel

I don't know anything about programming and even less about design patterns. I picked MVVM because it solved some of the issues with the objects structure of the application.

---

[Picture of the GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDRVJ.png)

The black area is a map with all the waypoints.

Active waypoint is the yellow circle.

Other waypoints are the green squares.

Clicking the "Set active WPT" button should change the map yellow waypoint. No problem so far as this is all done by the Map_Controller.

But this should also update the data in the "Waypoint 1 (Pond)" LabelFrame, which is in a different View and therefore has a separate Controller.

Note: All LabelFrame ("UAV", "Waypoint 1", "Control Station") are separate views, with separate controllers. The Map is a Canvas contained in a Frame, also with a separate controller.

QUESTION: How can I change the Waypoint_View when it has a different controller than the Map_View?
In MVVM, it seems like controllers cannot interact with each other.

I tried creating a ViewModel incorporating all models, with a single View and Controller. It makes the code fairly messy (maybe because I am not used to the large number of lines of code???) and seems like a bad practice anyways.

[EDIT]: Had multiple questions. Simplified to a single question.

Comment: Please only ask a single question at a time.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Edited to a single question.